# Magento and PayPal Pro - Sandbox mode - No Card Verification Number

Tags: magento, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've done some research on this forum and cannot really find an answer to this specific problem. I'm testing my Magento store (still in development) with PayPal Pro in Sandbox mode. I know that when I'm in developer.paypal.com, I can create customer accounts, which I have.

I went through the process to check out and pay on the website and got stuck at the Card Verification Number. I couldn't find this information under the customer account profile. Am I missing something?

I read something on a similar question: a set of random numbers will do the trick. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

I called PayPal support. They said that "123" works as the CVN most of the time. I tested it with my Magento store and it worked.